# Использование EventHandler C# .NET

Tags: c#, .net, события, handlers

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться в применении EventHandler. Я написал для проверки простую консольную программу:

```
internal class Program
{
    private class EventTest
    {
        private string Action { get; set; }
        private string Name { get; set; }

        public event EventHandler GeneralEventHandler;

        public EventTest()
        {
            Count();
        }

        private void Count()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                Action = $"Action {i}";
                Name = $"Name {i}";
                //Console.WriteLine($"{Action}\n{Name}"); //Для проверки

                CustomHandler(Action, new EventArgs());
            }
        }

        private void CustomHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            GeneralEventHandler?.Invoke(this, e);
        }
    }

    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var events = new EventTest();
        //events.Count();
        events.GeneralEventHandler += Events_GeneralEventHandler;

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static void Events_GeneralEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(sender.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
    }
}
```

Не работает, и вообще правильно ли так делать. Так же не могу получить доступ к свойствам например:

```
sender.Action
e.Action;
```

Хотелось бы обойтись без кастомного события:

```
 internal class Program
{
    public class MyEvents : EventArgs
    {
        public string Action { get; set; }
        public string DriveName { get; set; }

        public MyEvents(string action, string driveName)
        {
            Action = action;
            DriveName = driveName;
        }
    }

    public class EventTest
    {
        public string Action { get; set; }
        private string Name { get; set; }

        public event EventHandler GeneralEventHandler;

        public delegate void MessageReceivedEventHandler(MyEvents args);

        public event MessageReceivedEventHandler MessageReceived;

        public EventTest()
        {

        }

        public void Count()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                Action = $"Action {i}";
                Name = $"Name {i}";
                //Console.WriteLine($"{Action}\n{Name}");
                OnMessageReceived(new MyEvents(Action, Name));
            }
        }

        protected virtual void OnMessageReceived(MyEvents args)
        {
            MessageReceived?.Invoke(args);
        }
    }

    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var events = new EventTest();
        events.Count();
        //events.GeneralEventHandler += Events_GeneralEventHandler;
        events.MessageReceived += Events_MessageReceived;

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static void Events_MessageReceived(MyEvents args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(args.Action);
    }
```

В такой реализации все работает нормально... Можно ли это сделать через EventHandler передав в Invoke this?

Comment: `((EventTest)sender).Action`

Comment: А вообще, так нормально делать? Или лучше кастомное событие?

Comment: Кстати в `CustomHandler(this, new EventArgs());` что в качестве EventArgs передавать?

Comment: Лучше заводить отдельный класс `MyEventsArgs` и всю нужную информацию передавать с помощью него, т. к. сам объект отправляющий событие может к моменту обработки измениться, да и вообще не обязан иметь все нужные данные в виде открытых свойств

Comment: Благодарю за ответ!